# How will I load/cache the holidays from my database? It will be added to my DateTimeExtensions that already excludes weekends

Tags: c#, datetime

```
public static bool IsHoliday(this DateTime date)
{
  mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  mySqlCommand.CommandText = "Select date from HolidayTable”
  SqlDataReader sqlreader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

  List<DateTime> holidays = new List<DateTime>();  

  while (sqlreader.Read())
  {
      list.Add(reader.GetDateTime(0));
  }    
  holidays.ToArray();
  return holidays.Contains(date.Date);
}
```

How will i load the holidays from my database?

To replace this hardcode.

```
DateTime[] holidays =
new DateTime[] { 
new DateTime(2013,12,27),
new DateTime(2013,12,28)};
```

It will be added to my DateTimeExtensions that already excludes sunday and saturday on AddWorkDays()

Comment: Like this, no? Does this not work?

Comment: `holidays.ToArray();` will create an array that's not used at all. Assign it to a variable. However, you should really ask the database if the holiday exists, not load all into memory before you start looking for your date.

Comment: Or, statically load the holidays once, and keep it cached to avoid excess database calls.

Comment: Why is this not working? What goes wrong? What values do you have in your database and what values fails?

Comment: How i will cache the data from my database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static bool IsHoliday(this DateTime date)
{
ConnectionStringSettings myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["System.Properties.Settings.ConnectionString"];
SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString.ConnectionString);
mySqlConnection.Open();
SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Date FROM Holiday", mySqlConnection);
SqlDataReader sqlreader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

List<DateTime> holidays = new List<DateTime>();

while (sqlreader.Read())
{
holidays.Add(sqlreader.GetDateTime(0));
}
holidays.ToArray();
mySqlConnection.Close();
return holidays.Contains(date.Date);
}
```

I got the answer! Thank you :)